# Absorption Probability

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I am proving the next exercise:

Say if it's true or false. If it's true prove it, if its false give a counterexample. If $S$ is finite, $x \in S$ and $\left\lbrace C_i \right\rbrace_{i \in I}$ are the irreducible closed recurrents of $S$, then $$\sum_i\rho_{C_i}(x)=1$$

I divided the proof in two cases:

Case 1. $x \in S_T$

$\sum_i\rho_{C_i}(x)=\sum_i \mathbb{P}_x(T_{C_i}<\infty)=\mathbb{P}_x(T_{S_R}<\infty)$

Given that there is a finite number of transient states and every transient state is visited only finitely many times, the probability $\mathbb{P}_x(T_{S_R} < \infty)$ that a recurrent state eventually be hit is 1.

Therefore, $\sum_i\rho_{C_i}(x)=1$.

Case 2. $x \in S_R$

In this case the sum is not equal to 1, but I don't know which counterexample I can give.

Comment: What is $\rho C_i$?

Comment: $\rho_{C_i} (x) = \mathbb{P}_x[T_{C_i} < \infty]$ and is the absorption probability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But the second case is true. If $x \in S_R \Rightarrow x \in C_i $ for any $i \in I$

Once $x$ is in a closed set it doesn't comes out, this means: $$\rho_{C_i} (x) = 1$$ and $$\rho_{C_j}=0, i\neq j \Rightarrow \sum_i \rho_{C_i}(x)=1+0+0+...=1$$